# PHP date comparison

Tags: php, date, time

How would I check if a date in the format "2008-02-16 12:59:57" is less than 24 hours ago?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
if (strtotime("2008-02-16 12:59:57") >= time() - 24 * 60 * 60)
{ /*LESS*/ }
```

Answer (score 20):

Just adding another answer, using `strtotime`'s relative dates:

```
$date = '2008-02-16 12:59:57';
if (strtotime("$date +1 day") <= time()) {
    // Do something
}
```

I think this makes the code much more readable.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ((time() - strtotime("2008-02-16 12:59:57")) < 24*60*60) {
  // less than 24 hours ago
}
```

Answer (score 2):

e.g. via [strtotime](http://php.net/strotime) and time().
The difference must be less then 86400 (seconds per day).

```
<?php
echo 'now: ', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n";
foreach( array('2008-02-16 12:59:57', '2009-12-02 13:00:00', '2009-12-02 20:00:00') as $input ) {
  $diff = time()-strtotime($input);
  echo $input, ' ', $diff, " ", $diff < 86400 ? '+':'-', "\n";
}
```

prints

```
now: 2009-12-03 18:02:29
2008-02-16 12:59:57 56696552 -
2009-12-02 13:00:00 104549 -
2009-12-02 20:00:00 79349 +
```

only the last test date/time lays less than 24 hours in the past.

Comment: It's ok (i suppose) in the case where he needs "less than 24 HOURS". Just keep in mind not to assume that a day always has 24h (like you said in your answer). If you move from hours difference to days difference, you're better off using a DateTime library. For a better explanation of Time issues, you can check this article: http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php

Answer (score 2):

Php has a [comparison function between two date/time objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), but I don't really like it very much. It can be imprecise.

What I do is use strtotime() to make a unix timestamp out of the date object, then compare it with the output of time().

Comment: `DateTime` is PHP 5.3 and above only.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it.....

```
if(strtotime($date_start) >= strtotime($currentDate))
{
// Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be you variable date Like

```
$date_value = "2013-09-12";
$Current_date = date("Y-m-d"); OR $current_date_time_stamp = time();
```

You can Compare both date after convert date into time-stamp so :

```
if(strtotime($current_date) >= strtotime($date_value)) {
 echo "current date is bigger then my date value";
}
```

OR

```
if($current_date_time_stamp >= strtotime($date_value)) {
 echo "current date is bigger then my date value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be more easy to understand...

```
$my_date        = '2008-02-16 12:59:57';
$one_day_after  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2008-02-16 12:59:57 +1 days'));

if($my_date < $one_day_after) {
echo $my_date . " is less than 24 hours ago!";
} else {
echo $my_date . " is more than 24 hours ago!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simple PHP to do this:

```
$date = new simpleDate();
echo $date->now()->subtractHour(24)->compare('2008-02-16 12:59:57')->isBefore();
```