# DateTime::CreateFromFormat for PHP 5.2.14

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I am using the following code to convert user input into a mysql timestamp.

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:i a', "{$exp}");
$timestamp = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

where `$exp` would equal something like: 06/12/2013 6:41 pm

This works fine on my local server which is running PHP 5.4.3, but when I upload the same script onto my hosting server, It does not want to run this part probably because of the difference in PHP versions.

How would I go about fixing this or an alternative to it? Thanks!

Comment: What PHP is your hosting server running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extend the DateTime class and implement `createFromFormat()` yourself like this:-

```
class MyDateTime extends DateTime
{
    public static function createFromFormat($format, $time, $timezone = null)
    {
        if(!$timezone) $timezone = new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());
        $version = explode('.', phpversion());
        if(((int)$version[0] >= 5 && (int)$version[1] >= 2 && (int)$version[2] > 17)){
            return parent::createFromFormat($format, $time, $timezone);
        }
        return new DateTime(date($format, strtotime($time)), $timezone);
    }
}

$dateTime = MyDateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2013-6-13');
var_dump($dateTime);
var_dump($dateTime->format('Y-m-d'));
```

This will work in all versions of PHP >= 5.2.0.

See here for a demo http://3v4l.org/djucq

Answer (score 0):

To make a timestamp from a particular date...:

```
$time = "06/12/2013 6:41 pm";
$format = "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %P";
$ts = strptime($time, $format);
$ts = mktime($ts['tm_hour'], $ts['tm_min'], $ts['tm_sec'], $ts['tm_mon'], $ts['tm_mday'], ($ts['tm_year'] + 1900));
```

after you can use like you want:

```
$mysql_timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ts);
```

Comment: I'm getting: Fatal error: Call to undefined function strptime()

Comment: strptime only works under Linux OS

Comment: wrong, it's not implemented under Windows OS, and works even in OS X.