# How to get the next two saturdays from a specific date

Tags: php

I'am searching a lot without finding a solution.

Here is my code:

```
Post="2/28/2013"; 
$timestamp = strtotime($_POST['date']);
$datum = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

I would like to have the next two Saturdays following a date (named by user) to provide two auxiliary dates to customers. I take the date to look in mySQL to see if the date is available.

This gives the next Saturday from today, but it did not help:

```
$nextSaturday= date("M d Y", strtotime('+1 Saturday'));
```

Comment: `strtotime()` takes a second parameter ´$now´.

Comment: -4 downvotes!! I'am fear of asking a question again ;)

Comment: Any hint why it is downvoted? Or is it due to the rainy weather?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$nextSaturday= date("M d Y", strtotime($datum.' next saturday'));
$nextSaturday2= date("M d Y", strtotime($nextSaturday.'+ 1 week'));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: do not work: no result

Comment: @hamburger if you put it underneath your code it should return next saturday

Comment: you right. it works like a charm. I do not know why it is downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

The nicest way to do this is with the PHP `DateTime` classes:

```
$date = new DateTime($_POST['date']);
$date->modify('next Saturday');

echo $date->format('M d Y');
```

Comment: @hamburger No, it's relative to the DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = time();
$saturdaysCount = 2;
$saturdays = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $saturdaysCount; $i++){
    $time = strtotime("next Saturday", $time);
    $saturdays[] = date('Y.m.d', $time);
}

var_dump($saturdays);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes are definitely the way to go:-

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $_POST['date']);
$int = new \DateInterval('P1W');
$date->modify('next saturday');
$firstSat = $date->format('d-m-Y');
$date->add($int);
$secondSat = $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: sorry got an error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromForm

Comment: Your version of PHP does not have DateTime::createFromFormat(). I recommend updating if you can. Otherwise you may, or may not, be interested in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17076627/212940